# Installing Kubuntu 15.10 as a guest on Hyper-V

Tags: kubuntu, 15.10

I downloaded Kubuntu 15.10 AMD 64 today and tried to install it on my Windows 10 device under Hyper-V.  THe system boots but when I am unable to get past the 2nd screen to Continue.  I click on back, or any other option in within the installer, but I cannot click on "Continue" to finish the installation. Any ides?

Answer (score 3):

If you created a Generation 2 virtual machine in Hyper-V, you need to disable Secure Boot under **Settings** > **Security** > uncheck "Enable Secure Boot".

After that, it should be okay. Or, just use a Generation 1 virtual machine.

Comment: +1 for likely relevant answer; Quick googling also supports that Secure Boot need to be disabled for installing certain Linux distributions, including Ubuntu 64-bit.